# Bound the Frobenius norm of a matrix by largest entry and rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Suppose $A \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times n}$ is a rank $r$ matrix and $|A_{ij}| \leq B$ for all $i, j$. I can obviously write down the inequality 
$$
\|A\|_F \leq cB,$$
with $c = n$. But can we write $c = f(r, n)$ where $f(r, n) < n$? (For example, can I take $c = \sqrt{rn}$ or similar?).

As clarification $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm on the space of $n$ by $n$ real matrices.

Comment: Look at the matrix with all entries equal to $B$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I see. Then the frobenius norm is $$\sqrt{n^2B^2} = nB,$$ but the rank is $1$.